# Cursors in SQL Server not functioning

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

I have the following "Unit" table

```
     Description
    -------------
    PERCENTAGE
    KG * KILOMETRE
    KG * METRE
    KG * MILE
    KG * YARD
    POUND * KILOMETRE
    POUND * METRE
    POUND * MILE
    POUND * YARD
    TON * KILOMETRE
    TON * METRE
    TON * MILE
    TON * YARD
    TONNE * KILOMETRE
    TONNE * METRE
    TONNE * MILE
    TONNE * YARD
    COUNT * KILOMETRE
    COUNT * METRE
    COUNT * MILE
    COUNT * YARD
```

I have to transform each unit of form `A * B` to `A/B` and `PERCENTAGE` to `%` in the DB.
I wrote the following code using Cursors

**QUERY:**

```
DECLARE @textToDisplay varchar(50);
DECLARE CurrencyCursor Cursor Local
    For SELECT Description FROM Unit;

OPEN CurrencyCursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM CurrencyCursor into @textToDisplay;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    Begin
        @textToDisplay = 
              CASE @textToDisplay                        --line 1
                  WHEN 'PERCENTAGE' THEN '%'
                  WHEN '% * %' THEN REPLACE(@textToDisplay ,' * ', '/')     --line 2
                  ELSE @textToDisplay
              END
        Print @textToDisplay
        FETCH NEXT FROM CurrencyCursor into @textToDisplay;
    End

CLOSE CurrencyCursor   --line 3
```

I get the following errors:

```
`line 1` - Incorrect syntax near '@textToDisplay'

`line 2` - Incorrect syntax near '@textToDisplay'. Expecting '(', or SELECT

`line 3` - Incorrect syntax near 'CLOSE'. Expecting CONVERSATION
```

Cannot quite understand the cause of the errors.

Comment: This is most definietely not a job for a cursor. You should never use cursors for such things when set-based alternatives are available. A cursor is a last resort, never a first resort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @textToDisplay varchar(50)
DECLARE CurrencyCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT Patientid FROM Patient;

OPEN CurrencyCursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM CurrencyCursor into @textToDisplay;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    Begin
       SET  @textToDisplay = 
              CASE @textToDisplay                        --line 1
                  WHEN 'PERCENTAGE' THEN '%'
                  WHEN '% * %' THEN REPLACE(@textToDisplay ,' * ', '/')     --line 2
                  ELSE @textToDisplay
              END
        Print @textToDisplay
        FETCH NEXT FROM CurrencyCursor into @textToDisplay;
    End

CLOSE CurrencyCursor
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply use nested replace?

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(Description, '*', '/'), 'PERCENTAGE', '%')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add set/select in line 1 before the @textdisplay

```
Set @textToDisplay = 'something'
```

or

```
select @textToDisplay = 'something'
```

in your sql:

```
set @textToDisplay = 
        CASE @textToDisplay                        --line 1
           WHEN 'PERCENTAGE' THEN '%'
           WHEN '% * %' THEN REPLACE(@textToDisplay ,' * ', '/')     --line 2
           ELSE @textToDisplay
        END
```

Note:

do not forget the "DEALLOCATE Name_Cursor" at the end of your query.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @textToDisplay varchar(50);
DECLARE CurrencyCursor Cursor Local
    For SELECT Description FROM Unit;

OPEN CurrencyCursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM CurrencyCursor into @textToDisplay;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    Begin
        SELECT @textToDisplay = 
              CASE @textToDisplay                        --line 1
                  WHEN 'PERCENTAGE' THEN '%'
                  WHEN '% * %' THEN REPLACE(@textToDisplay ,' * ', '/')     --line 2
                  ELSE @textToDisplay
              END
        SELECT @textToDisplay
        FETCH NEXT FROM CurrencyCursor into @textToDisplay;
    End

 CLOSE CurrencyCursor   --line 3
```